# Cannot read property 'set' of undefined in dojo

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, dijit.form

i'm using the set property for enabling and disabling the button based on the checkbox click..while compiling getting error like this. **"Cannot read property 'set' of undefined"** can anyone please help.thanks in advance.

JS:

```
if(dojo.byId('pickLstValChkbox').checked === false){
    dijit.byId('isK9Acccepted').set('disabled', true)
}
else{
    dijit.byId('isK9Acccepted').set('disabled', false)
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="CHECKBOX" name="" dojoType='dijit.form.CheckBox' id="pickLstValChkbox" value="CONFIRM_CHECKED">
<button class="defaultButton" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="isK9Acccepted">Accept</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to call `parser.parse()` ( create and render dijits )

Then to access your dijit you have to use `dojo/ready` to ensure that all `dijit's` are loaded and rendered

In your case you want that when the checkbox is checked (unchecked ), you enable (disable) the button so, you have to use a `change` event on the checkbox dijit

note that modern dojo uses  `data-dojo-*` [ type, event , id ]insted of `dojoType or dojoEvent` ... in its html attrib .

here is a fiddle that may help you : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9up23q1/48/)

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs, when you are trying to access dijit controls before parsing. use `dojo.parser.parse();` before doing anything. more details can befound here. https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/parser.html

Also, which version of dojo are you using? Looks like you are using legacy way of coding. I would suggest you migrate to AMD style.